# Pepper leaves curling

Tags: diagnosis, peppers

this is my pepper plant, it's been curling up like this for a time and the flowers are not producing any peppers (i hand polinate it).

is this a virus? is it cureable? ty for your help[image]

[image]

Comment: What sort of soil were you using? Were there extreme temperatures?

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell for sure what it is just from the pictures, but one of my pepper plants did the exact same thing. The leaves curled up just like that, they were even rigid enough in that position to hold water there. Whenever I hand pollinated a flower, a day or two later it fell right off and no pepper left behind.

Long story short, what ended up fixing the issue for my particular plant was watering it less. I can't promise you that it is the same issue with your plant, but it is worth investigating some simple issue like watering, fertilizing (in particular over doing it) or temperature.

Answer (score 0):

Normally leaf curling down the length of a pepper leaf is a sign of some environmental effect on the plant (water, sun, fertilizer, temp), either too much or too little.  Gardening always seems to be either too much or too little with the same effect.

Sometimes I just stop doing all things to the plant for several days and then re-evaluate.